# Создать репозиторий gitbub

Tags: github

> git clone git@github.com:vitaly28/java-counta.git
>
> Cloning into java-counta'...
>
> The authenticity of host 'github.com <192.30.253.112>' can't be
>   established.
>
> RSA key fingerprint is
>   SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting ?

```
javac Calculate.java
java Calculate
```

Все работает.

```
git add Calculate.java
```

и на все остальные команды Выдает ошибку

> fatal: Not a git repository : .git

Answer (score 1):

У вас склонировало проект в папку `java-counta`, а вы скорее всего после клона продолжили работать в той же папке с которой и писали команду `git clone`.

Comment: И как же быть дальше подскажите

Comment: @ВиталийVit переходите в папку `java-counta` и из неё работаете

Comment: А что значит создать клон у мня создается папка хотя cmd выдает

Comment: C:\Users\вит>git clone git@github.com:vitaly28/java-counta.git
Cloning into java-counta'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com <192.30.253.112>' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting <yes/no>?

Comment: может я не все программы установил кроме github